# How to execute a C file in notepadqq for Linux?

Tags: c

I'm trying to run a C file using Notepadqq in Manjaro Gnome edition, but when I try running my script by going to the Run command it opt up a windows that says Special Placeholders
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf0HY.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to an image, please edit your post and type the text out there.

Comment: C files are not directly executable. You need to first compile your code, and then execute the generated binary.

Comment: so no solution for that? I'll have to use ide instead for C right?

Comment: @RakinRahman you can try `gcc %path% && ./a.out`. if it doesn't work, try moving to a shell script and run that script. "I'll have to use ide instead for C right" -- if you feel like you **have** to run the code from within your editor, then perhaps an IDE is what you're looking for. But you don't have to. Just build and run from a console window on the side of your editor.

Comment: @YakovGalka isn't the script should be like **gnome-terminal -x "gcc %path% && ./a.out"**

Comment: I never used `notepadqq`, so have no idea how exactly it executes that command line. But, if you want the output to be redirected to its output pane (if it has one), and the above command doesn't work, then i'm almost sure that you you want to use `sh` instead of `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: Please do not use images to replace an entire question when asking on stack, check out the guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This should be corrected fairly easily via the graphical user interface. No command or file modification should be necessary.
In Nautilus you can right click on the file to open.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to run a C file using Notepadqq in Manjaro Gnome edition, but when I try running my script by going to the Run command it opt up a windows that says Special Placeholders enter image description here

To run a C program you need to compile it first, generate an executable and then run it as a normal system command.  You cannot run it directly from Notepad++ because as such, it is not still executable.  This is generally done with a program called a C compiler (which you don't mention if you have one or not)  I figure that you are on a Windows computer, so the variety and availability of C compilers makes it impossible to continue giving you advice.  You need to install a compiler, learn how to use it, and then you'll know how to make your C program executable in the system.

I recommend you to read a good programming book in C, like "The C Programming Language" from Brian Kernighan & Dennis Ritchie, to know how to compile a program and your operating system's manual to know how to execute a program.

## Edit

Oh, sorry, you said on linux.  You have to save your source file (with some name ended in `.c`) then compile it with something like

```
$ cc my_hello.c -Wall -o my_hello
```

where `my_hello.c` is the name you gave to the C source file, `-Wall` makes the compiler to be more verbose in explaining your C programming errors and `-o my_hello` specifies the compiler to output the executable command in a file called `my_hello`.

(I have represented the system prompt as `$` and the screen cursor as `_`, you don't need to key those symbols) and then

```
$ my_hello
Hello$ _
```

(as you didn't end the line with `\n`, the next system prompt will appear next to your program's last message) to get it printed correctly, just modify your program to appear as

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello\n"); 
    /*           ^^-- insert the '\n' there */
}
```